# Limit as x approaches infinity for weird function

Tags: calculus

How would I determine what this function equals at x approaches infinity and negative infinity? $y= 2x^{5/3}-5x^{4/3}$. I know that we can use the end behavior of $x^{1/3}$, but I want to solve it without using that info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $$2x^{5/3}-5x^{4/3}=\left(2x^{1/3}-5\right)x^{4/3}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Write $f(x)$ as $$f(x)=x^{5/3}\left(2-5x^{-1/3}\right)$$